# UPnP with ushare to an xbox 360 arcade

Tags: 11.10, streaming, upnp, xbox-360, ushare

I am looking for sharing things like a folder with ushare. I got the program running with xbox to play the music but it crashes through a song. Does anyone know how to fix it?

My router is echolife (it came with the talktalk broadband). It looks like a picture frame you find it if you live in the UK.

Just want to ask if it can be fixed or if it is a router problem. Do I need to configure anything in ushare?

Comment: I have a similar problem with ushare, as it crashes as soon as i enable DLNA and restart it. [There is a bug filed on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ushare/+bug/886888) . But i dont have the solution for that, for now.

Answer (score 1):

After installation we need to configure **ushare** to meet our network settings. This can be done using the ushare configuration assistant

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ushare
```

We can also set configuration options in `/etc/ushare.conf`. For streaming to an XBox 360 make sure this file contains the following lines:

```
USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX=yes # for Xbox360 support
USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA=no # only needed for Playstation 3
```

The ushare service can then be started or stopped with

```
sudo service ushare start # stop for terminating
```

or by running **ushare** from the command line

```
ushare -D --name=<name_of_my_stream> --content=<path_to_mediafiles>
```

- For further options see also the [project home](http://ushare.geexbox.org/) page at geekbox.
- There is also a GUI to set up shared directories and start the stream ([stream2ip](https://launchpad.net/stream2ip)).
- If configured you can also use the ushare webinterface for configuring stream directories:  http://localhost:49200/web/ushare.html

Answer (score 0):

I use `rygel` to share media with the Xbox, no configuration required, just start it and it "just works". Very reliable and just an apt-get install ... away. https://live.gnome.org/Rygel

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd not recommend ushare since its development has been discontinued:

http://ushare.geexbox.org/

I use minidlna which is actively maintained and is small and lightweight:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/

Minidlna is in the repositories and can be configured for the xbox 360