# SSH Streaming Audio

Tags: ssh, mp3, mplayer, streaming

So I have been using *mplayer* to stream my music through SSH from my laptop to my Ubuntu box using:

```
ssh user@ip-address "cat /Some/Random/Directory/*mp3" | mplayer -
```

I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing this because currently I cannot skip through songs and such.

Does anyone know of a better way or a better program to stream music other than *mplayer*? Or perhaps some suggestion about the *mplayer* configuration?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/95718/3940) gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp), perhaps? You can stream music from it, play music on the hosting computer (if you want), and it can play your music on iPhone and Android devices, too (using special apps, of course).

Comment: I was looking for more of a command line approach. But I did not know about Subsonic. Pretty cool. I'll definitely have to check it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In that case, either make the server (laptop) publish a stream usimg icecast2 or something, or (my recommended approach) share the files on the network and play them using moc (media on console). Since you have ssh, using sshfs to mount the music folder is the simplest solution.