# What media servers support DLNA sharing?

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What DLNA server to choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1755/what-dlna-server-to-choose)

as the title says I´m searching for a mediaserver for Ubuntu 12.04.
I have already tried Mediatomb, Serviio, Miro (media management), Songbird (media management). But the thing is, that I need a mediaserver which is able to share the media via DLNA and which is performant, so optional with an external database server.
The problem is, that I have a very big media collection, and media management tools like Songbird and Miro are not performant with such a lot content.

Do you know some good server solutions for media management and sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [MiniDLNA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/)

We realise this here with the rather lightweight DLNA server MiniDLNA. This tool is available from the repositories. An updated version and good support can be obtained from the [project's page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/) with sourceforge.

When installing the DEB package from the repositories the application can be run by

```
sudo service minidlna start
```

using its default configuration file `/etc/minidlna.conf`. This file needs to be edited for defining media directories, database cache directory, and network properties. Scanning your media for changes in content will be done in defined intervals but you can also force a rescan at any time with:

```
sudo service minidlna stop
sudo minidlna -R
```

Scanning of the media for building the database may take quite a long time with large libraries or huge files. Once done it runs quite stable in the background. You can also define an upstart script to run on boot.

Settings for the init script can be made in `/etc/defaults/minidlna`. This is especially helpful when we want to run MiniDLNA as a certain user (e.g. when the database is stored in a HOME directory).

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA on how to run minidlna from userspace. You then may also be interested in the [MiniDLNA Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/175891/3940).

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend **XBMC** for your need.

For further details on how to install and use it. Please refer the previous askubuntu question.

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2652/how-do-i-install-xbmc) will help you on how to install XMBC

Hope this helps

Comment: I ever thought that XMBC is not able to share media via DLNA, but I will try it out.

Thank you for the fast response.

greetings