# DLNA on Ubuntu 1204 with gnome-classic icons in tray

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, samsung, multimedia

I am trying different DLNA systems to share media in my laptop wirelessly to a Samsung SMART TV. The ones I've tried so far, Serviio and tvmobili, seem to run as a deamon but don't show an icon in the tray. This might be due to me having gnome-classic instead of unity. Any suggestions for a DNLA system that will work for me?

Comment: We have a good experience for a Samsung SmartTV with [minidlna](http://askubuntu.com/a/182501/3940) and use it everyday here. We have it run as a daemon on startup - no tray icon needed but you need to edit the configuration files for setup.

Comment: I installed minidlna and it's very straightforward to set up and use. Not I have to figure out how to be able to fast forward/reverse the streamed content. Thanks.

Comment: Fastforward does not work with all sources (have not found out which work and which dont). It seems to depend on content. You also may have to update it with a newer version. But you can go to a position in a stream from the TV's menu. To our all delight MiniDLNA is very light and stable otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use `rygel` which works really well and can be run when you log in. It doesn't have an indicator or tray icon either though. Just copy the `rygel.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.config/autostart` to have it get run when you log in, after configuring it. It does have a GTK+ app for configuration, though.