# Media service on ubuntu

Tags: streaming, mediaserver

I have a ubuntu desktop on my home network which has a lot of files that i'd like to play on my tv. I have a logitec reveue (google tv) which is capable of streaming media on the lan.

So, I'm looking for recommendation on applications that can start a media service on my lan (like windows media center) so that the google tv can play files from that server.

Comment: Try XMBC http://xbmc.org/

Answer (score 0):

Due to a lack of hardware we obviously can't test this here but from what we can read

> Logitech Media Player should work with any DLNA certified server software, or any DLNA certified NAS device. <sup>[Logitech Support Forum](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Revue-and-Accessories/I-just-upgraded-and-now-I-can-t-play-any-of-my-UPnP-videos/td-p/754748)</sup>

the device should be able to receive content from any DLNA server running on your Ubuntu box. See

- [What DLNA server to choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1755/what-dlna-server-to-choose)

Personally I recommend [MiniDLNA](https://askubuntu.com/a/182501/3940) because of it being light and stable.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Serviio](http://www.serviio.org/) on my home server. It is a DLNA server that comes with a seperate client. In your case you would run both, client and server, on your desktop PC. One great thing is that it can look up meta information for your files. It also supports virtual folders like "Last added" or "Recently viewed".