# Folder Inclusion/Streaming

Tags: video-streaming, blu-ray, home-theatre

When I used Windows - I used Nero Media Home Essentials 4 to stream my videos to my LG Bluray player. All I did was click "Add Share" and select my "Movies" folder - then it showed up on my Bluray player.

How do I do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please only one question per "question". Thanks :)

Comment: For DLNA see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1755/what-dlna-server-to-choose and http://askubuntu.com/questions/182492/what-media-servers-support-dlna-sharing

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else who encounters this - the short answer is: you can't.

Minidlna is the best option I've found, but it takes twice as long to get the same thing done. 
It's been a huge frustration for me as a new Ubuntu user - though it DOES work and is actually quite capable of being MORE customizable once you figure it out.

Good luck.