# Setting up Ushare (Xbox 360 File Sharing)

Tags: file-sharing, media, xbox-360, ushare

I recently tried installing Ushare so I could share media between my laptop and Xbox. Could someone direct me as to how to change the settings so it can be recognized by my xbox.

Ushare.conf file:

> USHARE_DIR=/home/travis/Music,/home/travis/Videos
>   USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX=yes
>   USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA=yes
>   USHARE_IFACE=wlan0

Every time I start the process running the command `sudo service ushare start` I get a crash report. If there is a way to copy this crash report tell me so I can post it.

> ExecutablePath:
>   /usr/bin/ushare
>   Package:
>   ushare 1.1a-0ubuntu9
>   Title:
>   ushare crashed with SIGSRGV in avformat_open_input()

Comment: Updated in the Question section

Comment: Looks like a problem with your `/etc/ushare.conf` file. Can you start ushare successfully from the command line? `sudo ushare --content=<InsertYourMediaDirHere>`

Comment: Please post the sections `USHARE_DIR=`, `USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX=`, and  `USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA=` from your `/etc/ushare.conf` file.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89770/upnp-with-ushare-to-an-xbox-360-arcade

Comment: Ok I've got most things working with it my only problem now is that I can't get my Xbox 360 to "see" my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

To define a content directory when starting ushare as a service we have to edit the file `/etc/ushare.conf` as **root** (e.g. by running `gksu gedit /etc/ushare.conf`) and add the media directories separated with a colon like e.g.:

```
USHARE_DIR=/home/travis/Music,/home/travis/Videos,[...]
```

Replace `travis` with the name of your user.

We also need to make sure we use the appropriate network interface the xbox is attached to:

```
USHARE_IFACE=wlan0 # for wireless network 0, e.g eth0 when connected wired
```

In case we need to stream to a specific port (see xbox or router manuals for details on how to open ports) we can do so by defining this port:

```
USHARE_PORT=49200 # or any other port, if empty a random port is chosen
```

---

Alternatively we may run ushare from the command line using the following command:

```
ushare -D --name=<name_of_stream> --content=<path_to_mediafiles>
```

We can also define the interface, port, and more on the commandline (for all options see [manual from GeeXboX](http://ushare.geexbox.org/)).

Comment: This appears to have worked correctly on the computer but when searching for a pc on my xbox it is unable to find any.

Comment: @Travis: what does the crash report tell you?

Comment: I have sent the error report. Is there a log that I can copy it from?